# Almost-Everywhere definition

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I was doing a homework for measure theory, and had a question involving two functions being equal almost everywhere. I've solved the problem, but am not sure about this other example I thought of. Take $f,g : \{1,2\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be two functions such that $f(1) = f(2) = 0$, and $g(1) = 0, g(2) = 1$. Then if we take $M = \{\emptyset, \{1,2\} \}$, with $\mu(\emptyset) = 0, \mu( \{1,2\}) = 1$, then we have that the set of points where $f \neq g$ is obviously $\{2\}$. However, I am unsure of whether or not these functions are equal almost everywhere or not because $\{2\}$ is not a measurable set. I am inclined to say no because this is a complete measure and my homework claims if a function is equal to another measurable function almost everywhere on a set with a complete measure, then it is measurable, but clearly g is not measurable.  Would these functions be not equal almost everywhere because the set on which they aren't equal is unmeasurable? Any clarification would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: "Almost everywhere" means "on the complement of a set of measure $0$".  "On a nonmeasurable set" does not qualify.

Answer (score 0):

Your $g$ is not a measurable fucnbtion on $(\{1,2\},M)$, so the question of it being equal to $f$ almost everywhere does not even arise.

Your measure is already  complete, so you cannot even complete it to  make $g$ measuarable.